# Preventing IFRAME embedding, but with one exception

Tags: javascript, iframe

Let's say we have a web-page at a given location (like `www.foo.com/page1.html`) and that page contains this (global) code:

```
if (self != top) {
    top.location.replace(location.href);
}
```

So, if we try to load that page into an IFRAME, the page will "jump" out of the iframe into the browser window, which will (as a consequence) destroy the page that contained the iframe.

This is OK, but I would like to implement an exception to that rule. Specifically, there is this other page on a different domain (like `www.bar.com/page2.html`), and I would like that this other page **is** able to embed the first page via an IFRAME.

How would I have to modify the code of the first page, so that it allows to be embedded into the other page?

Is this OK?

```
if (self != top && top.location.href !== "http://www.bar.com/page2.html") {
    top.location.replace(location.href);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you'll be able to check the external parent page's URL because the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) should prevent access to any of its properties.

Maybe there is some trickery that I'm aware of that allows it anyway. Barring that, the best idea that comes to my mind is checking `document.referrer`. As far as I know, a document requested in an `iframe` will always have the embedding page's URL in the referrer across browsers.

If the referrer is `http://www.bar.com/page2.html`, the page is either in an iframe on that page, or it was linked to from there (which is the only really big shortcoming of this method: You can't tell for 100% sure whether it's an incoming link, or an iframe embed).

Obviously, the document's referrer is spoofable by the client but I don't think that's an issue here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it is an issue. The page (foo.com) is not owned by me, and I was going to ask the owner to give me (bar.com) embedding rights... But if anyone can spoof the `referrer` property, then that won't work here.

Comment: @Šime only speficic clients can spoof their own referrer; foo.com can't spoof it for all clients that visit the site. Specific clients can always sabotage your tests by simply turning off Javascript so you will never be 100% safe anyway

Comment: @Pekka What about bar.com. Can it set `document.referrer` of foo.com? I would say that it cannot (because of the Same Origin Policy), right?

Comment: @Šime yes, only bar.com will get foo.com as referrer, but not the other way round. It is set by the browser and read only. It can be spoofed in the client using e.g. a [Firefox extension](http://www.stardrifter.org/refcontrol/). Note that this method is unable to tell apart whether a user followed a link on foo.com to bar.com (which is the original idea of the referrer property) or is viewing an iframe embed. I don't think it's a big shortcoming because there will be no direct linking to bar.com but it's important to be aware of

Comment: @Pekka But foo.com is the page that i want to embed, and bar.com is the page that contains the IFRAME. So, foo.com is the one which referrer property points to bar.com.

Comment: @Pekka Sorry about all that confusion. If a Firefox plug-in can spoof the referrer property, then it is not secure. Anyone can spoof bar.com and as a result be able to load foo.com into an iframe.

Comment: @Šime sorry, I mixed the two up in my last comment. Re security: You won't be able to achieve perfect security using a JS solution anyway, as I could simply turn Javascript off and render all your checks moot. Do you really need this to be 100% uncircumventable for every possible client? Then this becomes orders of magnitude harder and needs a server-side approach.

Comment: @Pekka Well, as I said above, I would like to ask the owner of `foo.com` for embedding rights for my domain (`bar.com`). I  need a solution that would enable him to identify that his page is being embedded into my page, so that he can code an exception for that case. `document.referrer` sound like a good solution, but if one can use plug-ins to spoof it, than that creates an additional security concern for the owner of `foo.com`, which makes that solution unacceptable for him.

Comment: @Šime you will not be able to find a JavaScript based solution that is going to help you here, as they all can be circumvented on client side. If the owner of `foo.com` relies on a JavaScript based frame buster for total security, he is acting foolish. I'm fairly sure a `document.referrer` based approach is as good (and as worthless) as any client side security measure.

Comment: @Pekka Yea, I got you. Thanks for all the valuable info. And merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 1):

If you pass X-FRAME-OPTIONS http header with the value of SAMEORIGIN, most modern browsers (including IE8) will not let the content be iframed from an alien domain.

I thought it may help.