# how to detect my site is in iframe and remove iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to know that how can I know that my website is embedded in iFrame and remove iFrame to load my site as usual with url in address bar!

just like this one:

```
<iframe src="http://varzesh3.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158903/need-to-break-out-of-iframe-after-content-in-iframe-is-submitted

Comment: the solution is in this [question][1] itself


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527464/preventing-iframe-embedding-but-with-one-exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524449/google-homepage-will-not-load-in-an-iframe

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this quite easily by evaluating `self` and `top`, and then using `replace()` to break out of the frame:

```
if (self !== top)
    top.location.replace(self.location.href)
```